# How to interpret the "independent probability" of an event which may only happen once at most?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Good evening, everyone. I'm currently reading **Davy Paindaveine & Philippe Spindel (2023) Revisiting the Name Variant of the Two-Children Problem, The American Statistician, 77:4, 401-405, DOI:
10.1080/00031305.2023.2173293**, and, working through some of the preliminary probabilities, I got stuck on something I can't resolve:

> The second variant rather asks: for a two-children family having at
> least a girl whose name is Florida, what is the probability that the
> other child is a boy? See, for example, Mlodinow (2008) or Marks and
> Smith (2011). If two sisters may be given the same name, then this
> variant is strictly equivalent to the previous one: more precisely, if
> it is assumed that girls are independently named Florida with
> probability r, then the probability that the other child is a boy is
> 2/(4 − r). *To make the second variant of interest, one therefore needs
> to assume that two sisters may not be given the same name, in which
> case, under the assumptions associated with what we will call Model A
> below, the probability that the other child is a boy is 1/2,
> irrespective of r*

I'm trying to reason through the italicized part of the second variant as follows. The siblings are listed in order where $B$ is a boy, $G_F$ is a girl named Florida, and $G_F^C$ is a girl not named Florida:

$$\frac{P\{(B,G_F)\cup(G_F,B)\}}{P\{(B,G_F)\cup(G_F,B)\cup(G_F^C,G_F)\cup(G_F,G_F^C)\}}=\frac{2\times.5^2r}{2\times .5^2r+P\{(G_F^C,G_F)\cup(G_F,G_F^C)\}}$$

Now, where I'm getting stuck is resolving $P\{(G_F^C,G_F)\cup(G_F,G_F^C)\}$. If I reason as follows, I can get the right answer:

1. The probability neither sister is named Florida is $(1-r)^2$
2. So the probability at least one sister is named Florida is $1-(1-r)^2$
3. But I don't want to count the probability both are named Florida
4. So I subtract $r^2$, leaving $1-(1-r)^2-r^2=2r$
5. So the probability of two girls, one named Florida, is $.5^2\times 2r$.

What's confusing me is that I also feel like I should be able to do it this way:

$$P\{(G_F^C,G_F)\cup(G_F,G_F^C)\}=P(G_F^C,G_F)+P(G_F,G_F^C)=P(G_F^C|G_F)P(G_F)+P(G_F|G_F^C)P(G_F^C)$$
$$=.5^2[1r+r(1-r)]=.5^2[2r-r^2]$$

Where is this $-r^2$ term coming from? What's weird is that I was able to confirm that, reasoning this way, $P(G_F^C,G_F)+P(G_F,G_F^C)+P(G_F^C,G_F^C)=.5^2(1)$. Somehow the $(G_F,G_F)$ event has probability 0 like it's supposed to, but the probability of "exactly one sister named Florida" is off by exactly what $P(G_F,G_F)$ would've been if possible.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. The only explanation I have is that, as soon as we defined an independent probability $r$ of a girl being named Florida, we lost the right to treat "two sisters named Florida" as an impossibility excluded from the overall sample space. That would necessitate the first strategy I used, while invalidating my $P(G_F|G_F^C)=.5r$ and $P(G_F^C|G_F)=.5(1)$ conditionals in the second strategy. "May not be given the same name" appears to mean "exclude the $(G_F,G_F)$ event from consideration", and not "$P(G_F,G_F)=0$". However, even if this is correct, I still can't explain the fact that the second strategy gave a complete probability distribution.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think a key part here is '*under the assumptions of Model A*'..

Comment: @Snoop yeah, you're right. I see where I went wrong here. Lesson learned is, in the absence of clear notation, marginal tables keep the things straight that I mixed up in my second "solution".